# SwiftUI Chart line with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swiftui, graphics

I'm trying to do a chart with rounded corners like the picture below.

[image: Chart]

I've tried the following code in Path:

```
.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineCap: .round))
```

and

```
.stroke(Color.accentColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineJoin: .round))
```

Nothing seems to work, is this possible? Any option I try in both lines always shows the graph the same way (picture below)
[image]
I'm using SwiftUI, swift 5, iOS 15. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick searching finds many, many articles, examples, discussions, etc. This looks like a pretty good one: https://exploringswift.com/blog/Drawing-Smooth-Cubic-Bezier-Curve-through-prescribed-points-using-Swift

Comment: The "critical points" should be a "control points" not the beginning or end

Comment: @DonMag will check that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line width of 2 is going to have barely visible rounding, you're looking at a circle of one point radius. These two lines are drawn with and without rounded joins at a line width of 2:

[image]

And here with a line width of 10:

[image]

If your line changes direction sharply then it's going to have a point on it, because that's the shape of your data. You can cut off the points by experimenting with the miter limit on the stroke style. If you want to smooth out your data then you'll need to look at some sort of interpolation, but that may not be appropriate depending on what you're modelling. See "smooth interpolation" [here] for an example. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/working_with_vectors)

Comment: @jrturon You're right, thanks for point that out. I will try the miter limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.interpolationMethod(.cardinal)` on your `LineMark`.

Example:

```
Chart {
    ForEach(data, id: \.id) { item in
        LineMark(
            x: .value("Day", item.date),
            y: .value("Mood", item.value)
        ).lineStyle(.init(lineWidth: 6))
         .interpolationMethod(.cardinal)
     }
}
```